# Python: load resources without using __init__.py files

Tags: python, resources, jsonschema, init

I have a directory of JSON Schema files that's distributed with a python package.  Some code in the package uses the schema files to validate data.

The way I'm currently loading the schema files is like so:

```
from importlib import resources
from myapp.schema import v1 as schema_v1

...

def _schema_file(self, uri: str):
    return resources.files(schema_v1) / uri
```

But one thing I don't like: this requires sprinkling `__init__.py` files throughout the `schema/` directory for the `import` statement to work.  I'd rather the `schema/` directory has just the schema files and nothing else.

Is there a better strategy I should be using?  I'm definitely open to switching away from `importlib` if that's advisable, I know there are lots of options but haven't figured out which is the most favored these days.